# Checking if hash key exists within a Ruby each iterator

Tags: ruby

Playing with the 2 sum algorithm in Ruby.

I've initiated a hash t and then within an each iterator I'm trying to check if a key exists within t. 
For some reason the if statement seems to never evaluate t[target-n] as true if though I'm adding it in the else part.

```
def two_sum(nums, target)
    t={}
    a=[]
    nums.each do |n|
        if t[target-n]
            a << nums.index(n)
            a << nums.index(t[target-n])
            return a
        else
            t[target-n] = n
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: If you want to check if a hash has a key and do something based on the existence of the key and not the value that this key holds use the `.has_key?(key)` or `.key?(key)` method. That's the first thing you should check.

Comment: For some reason even if I use both `.has_key?(key)` or  `.key?(key)` for example: 
`t.has_key?(target-n)` it still doesn't work

Comment: What is the actual desired input/output of the method?

Comment: The algorithm isn't complete I'm just not sure why the hash check `t[target-n]` doesn't eval to true after it's added in the else statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you print this debug line `p "#{target-n}, #{t}"` at the beginning of the loop you can find out why.

```
...
nums.each do |n|
    p "#{target-n}, #{t}"
...
```

Using this call `two_sum([3, 5, 2, -4, 8, 11], 7)` you get printed:

```
# "4, {}"
# "2, {4=>3}"
# "5, {4=>3, 2=>5}"
# "11, {4=>3, 2=>5, 5=>2}"
# "-1, {4=>3, 2=>5, 5=>2, 11=>-4}"
# "-4, {4=>3, 2=>5, 5=>2, 11=>-4, -1=>8}"
```

As you can see, the key you are looking for is added by the `else` part of the code.

One possible option (brute force) is to build up the hash of pairs, skipping duplicated pairs. Then iterate over the hash populating the array a if each of the pairs in in `nums`.

At the end call `a` to be returned by the method.

```
def two_sum(nums, target)
    t={}
    a=[]
    nums.each do |n|
        t[target-n] = n unless t[n]
    end
    t.each { |k,v| a << [k,v] if nums.include? k }
    a
end
```

Comment: Take the arguments `two_sum([2,7,11,15]
9)`
It seems on the second iteration it should see that `t[target-2]` exists and evaluate to true

Comment: @Falko, the second iteration is `t[target-7]`, so it doesn't.

Comment: Great @igian when debugging, my sequencing was out. If I add duplicates `t[target-1]` will eval to true.